# iPad showing wrong storage usage

Tags: ipad

I am not able to upload the latest software update as it requires 3.8Gb (iSO 8.4.1). I have deleted all mail in my in, out, sent and deleted items folders and it is still showing that mail is 1.9GB!? How can I clear this to do the upgrade?

Comment: try restarting your ipad before doing anything rash. This often clears these memory issues.

Comment: HI, I did that but no luck :-(

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before. IOS hangs on to some files even though it should purge them. Often times it will also show up as the "other" part of usage in the space used graph being much bigger than it should. It's easy enough to fix though.

1. Back up your phone with iTunes. I would encrypt the backup so it saves your passwords.
2. Now we *wipe* the phone: **settings > general > reset** and erase all contents and settings.
3. Once that is done restore the IOS device. Plug it back into your computer and use iTunes to restore from the backup you just made.

Nine times out of ten that will get rid of all the cruft sitting around on your iPad (or iPhone).

*Why* this is necessary... well ask Apple.